# Sending mail from perl applications with SSMTP

Tags: email-server, perl, ssmtp

I am on host-server with Centos 7 and KVM virtualization. I have 2 guest systems which are in routed virtual LAN. One of them is WEB server, the other is a mail server. Web server has hostname example.com and mail server is mail.example.com (both have dedicated static ip's).

I want SSMTP to route all mails from applications to my mail server.

```
root=root
mailhub=mail.example.com:465
Hostname=example.com
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=no-reply@example.com
AuthPass=*PASS*
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

Maybe I am a bit misunderstanding, but the mail doesnt go out not from Mail::Sendmail nor from NET::SMTP_auth.

In WEB machine mail log I see:

```
...status=deferred (connect to mail.example.com[*IP_ADDR*]:25: Connection refused)
```

Please help to understand what's wrong.

Comment: I may not understand what you are looking to do. Are you simply trying to make your servers send mail outbound via your mail server at "mail.example.com"?

Comment: yes, absolutely

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you are trying to send an email and telling the SMTP server that the localhost name is example.com.

The SMTP server is most probably expecting a FQDN as the hostname, not a domain.

This could lead the SMTP server into thinking your machine's name is `example` and that it's domain is `.com`

Hostname should be the FQDN of the server sending the email.